# php time unexpected results

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I'm a little confused with the outcome of these strtotime functions, I would expect them to be the same but get completely different results:

```
echo strtotime(date('Y-m-d h:i:s',time()).' +1 hour')."\n";
echo strtotime('now +1 hour')."\n";
```

results in:

```
date('Y-m-d h:i:s',time(): 1340117163
now +1 hour: 1340160363
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Both give the same result for me: http://codepad.org/cr4GLC0k

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the 'h' in the string format passed into date(); I did a bunch of playing around and found that the difference was 12 hours, a perfect suspect.

Capitalize the H (unambiguous hours), and you should be good. :-)

Comment: Ah! Good catch! This one was driving me nuts! It didn't help that the codepad post showed it working! Thanks a bunch & Much appreciated!

Comment: It's a cool problem, since it will only show itself during the second half of the day; which could explain why some folks may not have been able to reproduce it.